# php | dynamic api call

Tags: php, api, endpoint

I am trying to create a dynamic endpoint for a API I am creating in order to include some data but only if it is required so I can use it in multiple places.

The idea is to have `api.domain.com/vehicle` to bring back basic vehicle information but if I did `api.domain.com/vehicle?with=owners,history` then the idea is to have a function which maps the `owners` and `history` to a class which will return data but only if it is required.

This is what I currently have.

```
public static function vehicle()
{
    $with = isset($_GET['with']) ? $_GET['with'] : null;
    $properties = explode(',', $with);
    $result = ['vehicle' => Vehicle::data($id)];

    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        array_push($result, static::getPropertyResponse($property));
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Which will then call this function.

```
protected static function getPropertyResponse($property)
{
    $propertyMap = [
        'owners' => Vehicle::owner($id),
        'history' => Vehicle::history($id)
    ];

    if (array_key_exists($property, $propertyMap)) {
        return $propertyMap[$property];
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, the response I'm getting is being nested within a index, which I don't want it to be. The format I want is...

```
{
    "vehicle": {
        "make": "vehicle make"
    },
    "owners": {
        "name": "owner name"
    },
    "history": {
        "year": "26/01/2018"
    }
}
```

But the format I am getting is this...

```
{
    "vehicle": {
        "make": "vehicle make"
    },
    "0": {
        "owners": {
            "name": "owner name"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "history": {
            "year": "26/01/2018"
        }
    }
}
```

How would I do this so it doesn't return with the index?

Comment: Instead of array_push, try array_merge.

Comment: don't use array push. You want each array entry to be keyed to the property. Use something like : `$result[$property] =  static::getPropertyResponse($property);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vehicle::history($id)` seems to return `['history'=>['year' => '26/01/2018']]`, ...etc.

```
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $out = static::getPropertyResponse($property) ;
    $result[$property] = $out[$property] ;
}
```

Or your methods should returns something like `['year' => '26/01/2018']` and use :

```
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    $result[$property] = static::getPropertyResponse($property) ;
}
```

Comment: @IncredibleHat `return $propertyMap[$property];` is in `getPropertyResponse()`, not in `Vehicle::history($id)`.

Comment: @IncredibleHat :) Thank you for your comment, that's interesting. I'm currently looking.

Comment: @IncredibleHat `static::getPropertyResponse($property)` returns `"owners": {"name": "owner name"}`. Agree? So in foreach, `$result[$property] = static::getPropertyResponse($property)[$property]`. No?

Comment: Like... I'm not sure where he gets `$id` from inside the method of `getPropertyResponse`. Its not passed in, and its not a class reference. Also as you mentioned it, what is the actual return of `Vehicle::history()` anyway? I got lost.

Comment: Yeah, I agree... there is something fishy going on in the return of the sub-sub-method... from the other class of Vehicle.

Comment: I bet you nailed it though. Your answer should definitely be a move to a solution to his problem.